# curl to get actual file only seems to get a download link

Tags: bash, curl

I run command

```
curl https://sw5-test.longboat.com/test1/admin/training/certificate/download?file=test1%2F5620cdf1-9510-407f-8851-eb1b84898a4c%2F4%2F1499333042.pdf
```

But it only returns this.

```
download?file=test1%2F5620cdf1-9510-407f-8851-eb1b84898a4c%2F4%2F1499333042.pdf
```

I obviously want the file itself. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the response headers (with `-v` or `-I`). That's most likely a 30X redirect response with a `Location:` header to the actual content.

Add `-L` or `--location` to the curl command line to make curl automatically follow the redirect and ask for it from the new URL.